# ASP.NET JQuery Datepicker inside DataGrid EditItemTemplate not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datagrid, datepicker

So I have this code to add a datepicker to a textbox.  It works fine on a regular textbox, but when I try to use it for a textbox inside my datagrid edititemtemplate, it doesn't do anything.  If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.  Here is my code:

The script part is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtMileageEntryDate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my asp.net code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLogbook" runat="server" Width="823px" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowDataBound="gvLogbook_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLogbook_OnRowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowDeleting="gvLogbook_OnRowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvLogbook_OnRowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="gvLogbook_OnRowUpdating">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserVehicleIDItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VehicleDesc") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserVehicleID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserVehicleID") %>'
                                Visible="false" />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVehicleDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileageEntryDateStatic" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMileageEntryDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />
                            <%-- %><asp:Calendar ID="calMileageEntryDate" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />--%>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OdometerStart" HeaderText="Odometer Start" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OdometerEnd" HeaderText="Odometer End" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purpose">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileagePurposeIDItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MileagePurposeDesc") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileagePurposeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MileagePurposeID") %>'
                                Visible="false" />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMileagePurposeDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MileageEntryComment" HeaderText="Comment" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Per request, here is my entire aspx file code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="MileageLogbook.aspx.cs" Inherits="VehicleMilageLogbook.MileageLogbook" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtMileageEntryDate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Panel ID="panelAccessControl" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Panel ID="panelAddVehicle" runat="server" BorderWidth="2">
        <h2>
            Mileage Logbook</h2>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerVehicle" runat="server" />
        <p>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvLogbook" runat="server" Width="823px" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                DataKeyNames="MileageEntryID"
                OnRowDataBound="gvLogbook_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLogbook_OnRowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowDeleting="gvLogbook_OnRowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvLogbook_OnRowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="gvLogbook_OnRowUpdating">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserVehicleIDItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VehicleDesc") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserVehicleID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserVehicleID") %>'
                                Visible="false" />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVehicleDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileageEntryDateStatic" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMileageEntryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />
                            <%-- %><asp:Calendar ID="calMileageEntryDate" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("MileageEntryDate") %>' />--%>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField  DataField="OdometerStart" HeaderText="Odometer Start" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OdometerEnd" HeaderText="Odometer End" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purpose">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileagePurposeIDItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MileagePurposeDesc") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMileagePurposeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MileagePurposeID") %>'
                                Visible="false" />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMileagePurposeDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MileageEntryComment" HeaderText="Comment" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="panelAccessDenied" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="You are not authorized to view this page."></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: which is your latest Jquery.?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why I have been downvoted.  Maybe if whoever did it would actually comment instead of just downvoting, I could fix whatever problem you perceive.  Otherwise, it is pointless to downvote anonymously.

Comment: I did not downvoted, Jquery means the plugin which is used to run the js code

Comment: Sorry, I'm very uneducated in Jquery / Javascript.  How can I find this out?

Comment: You need to learn from here http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, When I implemented your code on my page. I got some issue what you are not doing correctly.

1. The textbox Id which you are calling is not the same.
2. Each template field is generating the different `ID` for each textbox. So you need to find another solution for generating `ID`  at the runtime for the template field.
3. The page is inheriting the master page, so the ID which is generating for the first Row of the Template Field was like this `mainContent_grdUser_txtMileageEntryDate_0`.
4. You need to put your code all the scripts including the HTML's of Gridview inside
   `<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"> </asp:Content>`

When I implemented like this, it worked for me. Also you can check with your code for the first Textbox.

See the code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=mainContent_grdUser_txtMileageEntryDate_0]").datepicker({
            textboxImageOnly: true,
            textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yyyy / mm / dd",
            yearRange: "-40:+0",
            maxDate: new Date(),

        });
    });
</script>
```

Just see carefully the ID in the Javascript code, that was your main thing, which was stopping it from generating the datepicker.

See the [Image](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=14141931651515)

Comment: Thank you, man. Could you please tell what is the 0 at the end of ID mainContent_grdUser_txtMileageEntryDate_0